# Sort columns in pandas using custom order for unknown number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following columns in my pandas DataFrame

```
DB_0, ISBN_0, ISSN_0, Title_0, e-ISBN_0, e-ISSN_, DB_1, ISBN_1, ISSN_1, Title_1, e-ISBN_1, e-ISSN_1 .... DB_n, ISBN_n, ISSN_n, Title_n, e-ISBN_n, e-ISSN_n
```

I want to change it to custom order, some like this:

```
Title_0, DB_0, ISSN_0, e-ISSN_0, ISBN_0, e-ISBN_0, Title_1, DB_1, ISSN_1, e-ISSN_1, ISBN_1, e-ISBN_1, ..... Title_n, DB_n, ISSN_n, e-ISSN_n, ISBN_n, e-ISBN_n
```

How can I achieve this result?? I have tried everything etc but nothing works. Tried to search it on google but didn't find the answer. The problem is we don't know how many columns we will have at the end.

Comment: Hint: use `sorted` with custom key

Comment: @coldspeedI tried everything, maybe you can explain it a little bit more. I don't know why my question got a negative vote though

Answer (score 0):

Use a template `order`:

```
l = ['DB_0', ' ISBN_0', ' ISSN_0', ' Title_0', ' e-ISBN_0', ' e-ISSN_', ' DB_1', ' ISBN_1', ' ISSN_1', ' Title_1', ' e-ISBN_1', ' e-ISSN_1', ' DB_2', ' ISBN_2', ' ISSN_2', ' Title_2', ' e-ISBN_2', ' e-ISSN_2']
order = ["Title", "DB", "ISSN", "e-ISSN", "ISBN", "e-ISBN"]
new_columns = [
    "{f}_{n}".format(f=f, n=n)
    for n in range(int(max([x.split("_")[1] for x in l])) + 1)
    for f in order
]
print(new_columns)

>>> ['Title_0', 'DB_0', 'ISSN_0', 'e-ISSN_0', 'ISBN_0', 'e-ISBN_0', 'Title_1', 'DB_1', 'ISSN_1', 'e-ISSN_1', 'ISBN_1', 'e-ISBN_1', 'Title_2', 'DB_2', 'ISSN_2', 'e-ISSN_2', 'ISBN_2', 'e-ISBN_2']
```

**Update: explanation**

`order` is used as a template for the specific field order you wanted to describe a single item.

Now, your columns are composed of an unknown number of items.

I find the number of items with this unelegant method:

```
int(max([x.split("_")[1] for x in l])) + 1
```

Then I use a list comprehension to loop over item numbers and fields (in the same order as my `order` list) to 
create strings of the form "field_number", `{f}_{n}` in the code:

```
new_columns = [
    "{f}_{n}".format(f=f, n=n)
    for n in range(int(max([x.split("_")[1] for x in l])) + 1)
    for f in order
]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lante Dellarovere It worked perfectly. Can you explain what you did?

Comment: added explanation. Glad it helped

Comment: Dellarovere Thank you so much